# Closure and lm in R

Tags: r, closures, lm

Hi i tried to prepare a little demo code for closures in R when i stumbled into some odd behavior. From using Debug i realize that the failure happens due to the fact that inside of lm this line is being executed

```
mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
```

however it seems to defeat the functional aspect of programming with closures ?

what am i missing ?  here is my little example

```
# typical closure use 
foo <- function(formula,data,weight=NULL) {
  if(is.null(weight)) w=ones(nrow(data),1) else w=weight    
  force(w)  
  lm(formula,data,weights=w)
}

setup_something <- function(...) {
   function(formula,data) {
     foo(formula,data,...)
   }
}

# set up our model function
model <- setup_something()

# set up our data 
df = data.frame(x=seq(1,10,1),y=c(1:10)^1.5 * 3 + 2)
model(y~x,df)
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'w' not found

Comment: It may be helpful: [Scoping issues](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#scoping-issues)

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating a formula (i.e.`x~y`) captures both the environment it is created in, which in your cases happens in the `parent.frame()` of your call to `model()`.

If you want to subjugate the environment, you can do so explicitly by adding this line right before your call to `lm(formula,data,weights=w)`:

```
# explicitly replace the formula's environment with the current frame
attr(formula,'.Environment')  <-  sys.frame(sys.nframe())
```

or implicitly by by replacing your call to `lm(formula,data,weights=w)` with:

```
#instantiate a new forumla based on the existing formula
lm(stats::formula(unclass(formula)),data,weights=w)
```

By way of background, if you were to stick the following line into `lm()` right before the call to `mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())`:

```
print(ls(envir=parent.frame()))
```

you would get a list of object names that includes `"w"`.  However, the 'mf' object being evaluated is a `stats::model.frame` thanks to this line:

```
mf[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
```

and `stats::model.frame` evaluates the arguments to `mf` in the context of the `.Environment` attribute of the formula.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a great explanation i did miss the fact that formula also captured an environment . thx b:)